# mysql row merge with LIMIT and where colose

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row, sql-order-by

This is my table named OS , i need bellow mentioned output.

```
id  | os        |
-----------------
1   |windows XP |
2   |mac        |
3   |windows XP |
4   |windows Xp |
5   |linux      |
6   |mac        |
7   |Windows NT |
8   |linux      |
9   |Windows NT |
10  |mac        |
11  |linux      |
12  |mac        |
13  |windows XP |
14  |linux      |
15  |Windows NT |
16  |mac        |
17  |linux      |
```

i want get two id from each os,

anybody can suggent a mysql query ?

**expected output**

```
1
3------------ windows xp
2
6------------mac
5
11----------linux
7
9----------windows NT
```

Comment: what is relation between this output ?  please add more specific relation for your desired  ouput.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
(
    select min(id) as id, os from os_table group by os
    union 
    select max(id), os from os_table group by os
) tmp
order by os
```

If  you don't need a specific order then remove the outer select

Comment: i need two id from each os.

Comment: And the result of my query is not what you want because?

Comment: Thank you dear, i am a java developer, not DB eng, so i was poover in sql, i got my out put using union. thank you, 'union is my new knowlege'